# error: invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo java, y estoy creando un clase Perro con metodos get para obtener los valores de las variables privadas

```
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private String nombreDuenno;
    public Perro (String nombre, int edad, String nombreDuenno) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.nombreDuenno = nombreDuenno;}
    public getNombre () {/*Perro.java:8: error: invalid method declaration; return type required*/
        return this.nombre;}
    public getEdad () {/*Perro.java:10: error: invalid method declaration; return type required*/
        return this.edad;}
    public getNombreDuenno () {/*Perro.java:12: error: invalid method declaration; return type required*/
        return this.nombreDuenno;}
```

Comenté en el codigo el lugar donde aparecían los errores.
Necesito otros ojos para ver los errores, ya que, segun el documento con el que me guio, está bien

Comment: Al nombre de tus métodos no les hace falta el tipo de dato que planean devolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función debes de indicar el tipo de dato que devolverá la función (int, char, float, String, double...)

```
public String getNombre () {
        return this.nombre;
}
public int getEdad () {
        return this.edad;
}
public String getNombreDuenno () {
        return this.nombreDuenno;
}
```

Comment: Gracias. me acababa de dar cuenta, y esto era lo que iba a escribir